# IIS 6 FTP Junctions "volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: windows, ftp, iis, junction, iis-6

I have created a junction in Windows to give isolated folder access to several users. However, I receive the following error when trying to list the files whilst connected via MS IIS 6.0 FTP server:

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list.
550 .: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The strange thing is I can happily use `cd` to navigate through the sub-folders. Although, I do receive an `Access Denied` error message when creating directories.

On a side note. I can navigate the directory's fine over CIFS/SMB and on the local filesystem. Additionally, I have configured a similar setup on IIS 7 with no problems. I have seen a few MS KBs surrounding this error with Junctions on IIS 7 I don't know if there is an issue with IIS 6?

Comment: Is it a junction or a symbolic link? They are not the same.

Comment: In 2008+ I am using the C++ function CreateSymbolicLink http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx which works fine. I am using Junctions for pre 2008 systems. Is there a better method?

Comment: Using sysinternals Process Monitor I can see its trying to get at the directory: "C:\C:\path\to\ftp\LocalUser\mikej\" which is invalid. I'll try and track down the double "C:\C:\" Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating: WIN-3489034\mikej